# Determine Frequency from Noisy Signal With Neural Networks (With Adeline Model)

Tags: neural-networks, signal-processing

I'm trying to determine the frequency from a signal with NN. I'm using the Adeline model for my project and I'm taking a few samples in each 0.1-volt step in a true signal and a noisy one.

First question: am I wrong?

Second question: my network works fine until the frequency of my sample for the test is equal to the frequency of my sample for the training. Otherwise, my network doesn't work and gives me the wrong answer. 
What do I need to do for this model?
for solving this problem I must use nonlinear steps like logarithmic steps. but How to use logarithmic steps in MatLab?

Edition: I understand my problem is not Overfitting! I found that my samples step are linear and my samples are nonlinear so this is wrong
for solving this problem I must use nonlinear steps like logarithmic steps. but How to use logarithmic steps in MatLab?

Comment: Tanks for edit Glorfindel :D